# list of different vector types?

Tags: c++

I need to maintain a list of vector(int), vector(char) and vector(float). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, why is there a problem ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: Could you expand on how you do this without resorting to type-casting?

Comment: How will it be used and how will the program want to know it an element is a vector<init> or a vector<char>?

Comment: @Rajesh: As Mark said, could you add a little detail to your question about how you would like to use such a list?

Comment: It cant be done by typecasting. I require it to be a vector of the actual type. The list is converted to a list recognized by another compiler, so it has to be a list of the actual types

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth -  Where did the OP mention it has to be a single vector ?

Comment: I'm hoping for something like list(vector(unknown)) , list.push_back(vector(char)),list.push_back(vector(int))

Comment: @DumbCoder: He doesn't, and I wasn't assuming that he had!

Comment: @Rajesh: Right, but assuming you *could* do this, what are you going to do when you extract items from your list?  How are you going to know what type they are?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I dont have to bother with that, once its recognized by another compiler my work is done

Comment: @Rajesh: I don't think so.  What use is a `vector<unknown>` (assuming such a thing existed)?  In what circumstance are you going to be able to do anything useful with that?

Comment: Ok, let me explain. If you've heard of Rcpp, it allows you to execute c++ code in R. so basically, if you had a c++ vector, you could convert it to a vector in R. Now, I want a list of vectors in R. If I had a list of vectors in c++, I'd just have to call a function and it would be done.

Comment: which is why, it has to be list(int,char etc.)..it becomes a list(int,char) in R.

Comment: @Rajesh: Sorry sir, but your question is still not clear. Maybe you should use some code to clarify your question?

Comment: @Rajesh: So are you saying that at runtime, the thing that accepts your `list` will expect the first item to be a `vector<int>`, and the second item to be a `vector<char>`, etc. (for instance)?  Essentially, it will perform a `reinterpret_cast` on each item to a pre-determined type?

Comment: It'll expect vectors, and convert accordingly. You dont have to bother about the type. I just need to be able to iterate over all my vectors and call the function

Comment: @Rajesh: Please see my answer and let me know whether that is what you want.

Comment: @Missing Faktor No :( It has to be a vector or a standard datatype, nothing else is recognized.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I understand your question.

Is [`boost::variant`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html) what you are looking for? It will allow you to store the elements with different types in a single container.

---

**Some sample code (not tested):**

```
typedef boost::variant <
  std::vector<int>, 
  std::vector<char>, 
  std::vector<float>
> VectorOfIntCharOrFloat;
std::list<VectorOfIntCharOrFloat> vec;
```

and then iterate over it / access elements as:

```
std::list<VectorOfIntCharOrFloat>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
while(itr != vec.end()) {
  if(std::vector<int> * i = boost::get<std::vector<int> >(itr)) {
    std::cout << "int vector"<< std::endl;
  } else if(std::vector<float> * f = boost::get<std::vector<float> >(itr)) {
    std::cout << "float vector" << std::endl;
  } else if(std::vector<char> * c = boost::get<std::vector<char> >(itr)){
    std::cout << "char vector" << std::endl;
  }
  ++itr;
}
```

Comment: Prefer use of ++itr - it's faster.

Comment: @steve: why is ++itr faster than itr++ in this case (or in general)? Thanks.

Comment: Because it doesn't have to create a copy of itr before incrementing.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    struct WrapperBase
    {
        // WrapperBase needs to be polymorphic for dynamic_cast
        virtual ~WrapperBase()
        {  }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct VectorWrapper : public WrapperBase
    {
        std::vector<T> vector;
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<WrapperBase*> vectors;

        vectors.push_back(new VectorWrapper<int>());
        vectors.push_back(new VectorWrapper<char>());
        vectors.push_back(new VectorWrapper<double>());

        for (int i=0; i < vectors.size(); ++i) {
            WrapperBase *v = vectors[i];
            if (dynamic_cast<VectorWrapper<int>*>(v) != 0) {
                std::cout << "It's an int vector.\n";
            }
            else if (dynamic_cast<VectorWrapper<char>*>(v) != 0) {
                std::cout << "It's a char vector.\n";
            }
            else if (dynamic_cast<VectorWrapper<double>*>(v) != 0) {
                std::cout << "It's a double vector.\n";
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i < vectors.size(); ++i) {
            delete vectors[i];
        }
    }
```

This has some drawbacks though:

- You need to use pointers, so be careful with memory leaks.
- `dynamic_cast` may be slow, I wouldn't use it in a tight loop.

Comment: `boost::variant` provides this exact functionality, so you're basically reinventing the wheel. Anyway as OP said R can recognize only lists of vector or primitive data types, so this solution also won't work.

Answer (score 1):

From the conversation thread on the original question, my understanding of the problem is that you have some "black-box" function whose interface is a list of vectors, whose individual types are known at runtime on both sides of the interface, but not represented in the interface itself.

If this is the case, would a simple `union` suffice?  e.g. (untested):

```
typedef union
{
    std::vector<char>    c;
    std::vector<int>     i;
    std::vector<float>   v;
} unknown_t;

std::list<unknown_t> my_list;

unknown_t u1;  // assume int
unknown_t u2;  // assume float

u1.i.push_back(5);
u1.i.push_back(10);

u2.f.push_back(23.4f);
u2.f.push_back(19.2f);
u2.f.push_back(1e6);

my_list.push_back(u1);
my_list.push_back(u2);
```

**UPDATE**

Oh, crap, this won't work.  You can't put `vector`s in a `union`, as they have copy-constructors.  Sorry!

Comment: how would I pass the vector to the blackbox function if it is of type "union", thats not recognized

Comment: the blackbox function only recognizes vectors of standard types

Comment: @rajesh: It sounds from your question as if you have no control whatsoever over the interface (i.e. it already exists).  If that is the case, please add to your original question details on *exactly* what the existing interface is that you have to adhere to.

Comment: As far as I remember, a union of non POD types causes undefined behaviour. §9.5.1 says: "An object of a class with a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor
(12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a
union, nor can an array of such objects."

Comment: @Oli: Union of non-POD types cause UB. Consider using `boost::variant` instead.

Comment: @DerKuchen: I just realised exactly this, so have updated my answer!  Please down-vote it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think now I understand it better.  You should make a wrapper class for each type of vector that you may encounter, and make all of them inherit from the same base class, say `AbstractVector`.  Then you can have a list of AbstractVector objects.

Comment: the problem is that I dont know beforehand what the vector types are gonna be, I get that info dynamically and create the vector types

Comment: DerKuchen's answer is exactly what I was talking about.  However, just keep in mind, that C++ isn't very well suited for dealing with collections of mixed types.  You seem to be fighting the language, and that may be an indication of a deeper problem with your design, or it simply may be that C++ is not the best language for your project.